IntelliJ warning - The result is always true (or false)
I have those 3 methods
public static boolean isMissing(String value) {
    return value == null || value.isEmpty();
}
public static <T> boolean isMissing(T object) {
    return object == null;
}
public static <T> boolean isMissing(List<T> list) {
    return list == null || list.isEmpty();
}

Which are unit tested with
@Test
void isMissing_string(){
    assertTrue(ValidationService.isMissing((String) null));
    assertTrue(ValidationService.isMissing(""));
    assertFalse(ValidationService.isMissing("abc"));
}
@Test
void isMissing_object(){
    assertTrue(ValidationService.isMissing((Integer) null));
    assertFalse(ValidationService.isMissing(1L));
}
@Test
void isMissing_list(){
    assertTrue(ValidationService.isMissing((List<Integer>) null));
    assertTrue(ValidationService.isMissing(List.of()));
    assertFalse(ValidationService.isMissing(List.of(1L)));
}

Why is IntelliJ telling me:
Result of 'ValidationService.isMissing((String) null)' is always 'true'
Result of 'ValidationService.isMissing((Integer) null)' is always 'true' 
Result of 'ValidationService.isMissing(1L)' is always 'false' 
Result of 'ValidationService.isMissing((List<Integer>) null)' is always 'true' 

I don't understand if there is really something wrong in that code or if it a 'bug' of IntelliJ?

The messages that IntelliJ is telling you are all correct, aren't they? What's problematic about this?

Result of 'ValidationService.isMissing((String) null)' is always 'true' Is there anything surprising about this statement? Do you consider it correct or incorrect?

I everything is ok why there are no messages on assertion 2,3,7 and 8 ?  Even more those messages are reported in the problem tabs and when I'm doing a commit and push it is telling me there are problems so I have to click again on commit and push anyway.

In production code I would not usually write an expression that always evaluates to true (except if I literally write true). So I would like IntelliJ IDEA to make me aware if I happen to do, so I can consider whether it’s what I meant or the expression can be simplified. In a unit test it’s different: the point of assertTrue(...); is exactly that the expression should always be true. IntelliJ employs the same checker in both cases and therefore in your test code issues messages that are correct but not really helpful.

IntelliJ reports these warnings because it does some simple dataflow analysis for null / not null values.

Having ValidationService.isMissing((String) null) in production code would be a strong indication of a bug, as the return value can be known before executing it, so it's pointless and thus was likely intended to be something else. That's why IDEA warns you. For your tests it's fine to verify this actually behaves as intended. Just silence that warning here.

As @ThomasKläger says, in the case of ValidationService.isMissing((String) null), IntelliJ IDEA can based on null analysis alone determine that the expression is true. In the case of ValidationService.isMissing("") the value depends on what String.isEmpty() returns, which IntelliJ does not try to analyse (or at least doen’t successfully fully analyse). Hence the message from the former and not from the latter.

The corresponding inspection in IntelliJ is "constant values" (for Java code) and you can configure it so that it is only reported for production code.

So ... the code is right but the assertions with null are useless ?
Or the code must be optimized ?

IMHO there are two possible solutions: (1) do you really need unit tests for these rather simple methods or is the code coverage achieved through the tests for the callers of these methods sufficient? (2) create parameterized tests for these methods. Using parameterized tests your test methods will have two parameters: value to use for the call to isMissing() and expected result and the (only) assertion in the test methods would be assertEquals(expected, isMissing(param));

@tweetysat The code is right.I don’t see any optimization to do.

Related: IntelliJ-Idea disable inspection: Actual value of parameter is always
